# Will squadmates using both disruptor and incendiary ammo be able to create power combos?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If I have both Ashley and James in my team and they are using their ammo powers (disruptor and incendiary), can they set off power combos while shooting at the same enemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Ammos can only set up detonation combos, but they cannot trigger them.

Comment: I guess, since I never even once observed any detonations during the Mars mission, it must be true. But can you still point to any (un)official source to confirm this, if there is any?

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic if you look at [power combos](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Combos) on the wiki, you'll notice that all the ammo powers are only listed under source powers.  Also, I've spent hundreds of hours in the game using a wide variety of ammos and I rely heavily on detonations since I typically play on the higher difficulties.